# Spree customization in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

Best way to customize a spree application in rails and from where i can see the existing code of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view the default spree code at its git hub site https://github.com/spree/spree.

The best way to customize a Spree site is through deface overrides, a good example of which can be found in the code for a pre-existing Spree theme, e.g. the theme for the demo spree site RDR which can be found at https://github.com/spree/spree_rdr_theme.

Basically any page that already exists within the Spree code base can be overridden using Deface, a simple introduction can be found in the Spree customization guide http://guides.spreecommerce.com/customization.html

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. But I want to know that where it is stored on my local system? I am using Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: When I installed Spree on debian it also didn't store the source locally, as a work around I simply cloned the git stable branch to have a local code reference, a little searching may find it somewhere on the system but I could't find it...

Comment: Yeah rolands, I am also unable to find it. If you finds it somewhere then u please acknowledge me also. your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

U can found it on the machine...

1. locate your app
2. run command, `"bundle show spree`"

for example on my machine :

```
/home/rathore/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/spree-1.2.0
```